# C# String text into another string variable

Tags: c#, string

I have this code:

```
string str1 = "Button1";
string str2 = "Button2";
string str3 = str1 + " " + str2;
```

What I want is to copy the text from `str3` (`"Button1 Button2"`) so that

```
string str4 = "Button1 Button2";
```

Why do I want such a thing, you may ask? It's because of this method that I'm trying to develop:

```
    public void SearchNumpadNumbersOnMyApp(double valueRepoItemName)
    {   
        valueRepoItemName = Math.Abs(valueRepoItemName);        
        string repoItemName;
        string result = string.Format("{0:F1}", valueRepoItemName);
        int length = result.Length;         
        char[] arrayOfCharacters = result.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {                   
        repoItemName = "Button" + arrayOfCharacters[i].ToString();

        // Query RepoItemInfo objects based on the repository item name 
        IEnumerable<RepoItemInfo> myQuery = from things in repo.FO.FLOW2FO.Container2.SelfInfo.Children
                    where ReferenceEquals(things.Name, repoItemName)
                    select things;
        // Create "unkown" adapter for the first found element and click it
        myQuery.First().CreateAdapter<Unknown>(true).Click();               
        }               
    }
```

When I pass `repoItemName` to

```
where ReferenceEquals(things.Name, repoItemName)
```

I get the error message `"Sequence contains no elements"`, and this occurs when I try to pass `repoItemName` string. This is the same as passing

```
where ReferenceEquals(things.Name, "Button" + arrayOfCharacters[i].ToString())
```

and this is the reason why I'm getting the error. So, what I want is to pass the actual text of the string and not its reference. I want it to be, for example, like this:

```
where ReferenceEquals(things.Name, "Button5")
```

Being "Button5" the string structure built with:

```
repoItemName = "Button" + arrayOfCharacters[i].ToString();
```

By the way, I already tried:

```
String.Copy();
String.Clone();
```

but nothing seems to do what I really want.

Comment: You likely want to replace `ReferenceEquals(things.Name, repoItemName)` with `string.Equals(things.Name,  repoItemName)` because you want to compare the equality of what the strings represent, not the equality of where each string is residing in memory.

Comment: Why are you checking references instead of the actual value? as @Quantic said you just need to do a string equals...

Comment: You my friend, just solved my problem, thank you so much!!! :) Massive hug for you!

Comment: No need for the char array `repoItemName = "Button" + result[i];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was this:

```
    IEnumerable<RepoItemInfo> myQuery = from things in repo.FO.FLOW2FO.Container2.SelfInfo.Children
        where String.Equals(things.Name, repoItemName)
        select things;
```

Thanks to all of you guys that helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
IEnumerable<RepoItemInfo> myQuery = from things in repo.FO.FLOW2FO.Container2.SelfInfo.Children
                where ReferenceEquals(things.Name, repoItemName)
                select things;
```

to

```
IEnumerable<RepoItemInfo> myQuery = from things in repo.FO.FLOW2FO.Container2.SelfInfo.Children
                where things.Name == repoItemName
                select things;
```

You want to compare the content of the strings, not the references. A `string` in C# is an immutable *class*. So

```
string str1 = "button1 button2";
string str2 = new string(str1.ToCharArray());
```

`str1` and `str2` are *equal* strings, but the two variables reference two different *instances of `string`*. Thatswhy `ReferenceEquals(str1, str2)` will always return `false`.

Comment: Just FYI your example `string str1 = "button1 button2";
        string str2 = "button1 " + "button2";
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(str1, str2));` returns `True`, I assume because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112610/referenceequals-working-wrong-with-strings).

Comment: @Quantic I already feared that this example is not good, because of those damn smart compilers. I changed the example, but now I'm not sure if it's not more confusing...

Comment: @René Vogt I swapped my code with your code and it didn't compiled. Although I already found the solution provided by the user Quantic

Comment: @kenzoviski that's because I used the `equals` keyword in wrong context. Changed it to `==`, but you may use the `string.Equals()` from Quantic as well.